# excel vba code to find value in a column are slow, how do i make it faster?

Tags: excel, vba, find, range, offset

My vba code below, how do it faster ?  (obs: i have +- 33000 lines of values)
I search codes from products to my company, i need help to do it faster.

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()
Dim FindString As String
Dim Rng As Range
FindString = TextBox1.Text
If Trim(FindString) <> "" And Len(TextBox1.Text) = 6 Then
   With Sheets("CADMAT").Range("B:B") 'searches all of column B
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                    After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                    LookIn:=xlValues, _
                    LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                    SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                    MatchCase:=False)
    If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
        Dim ultimalinha As Object
        Set ultimalinha = Plan3.Range("A35565").End(xlUp)
        ultimalinha.Offset(1, 0).Value = TextBox1.Text
        ultimalinha.Offset(1, 1).Value = TextBox2.Text
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    Else
        MsgBox "Produto não existe na tabela!" 'value not found
        TextBox1.Text = ""
        TextBox2.Text = ""
        TextBox1.SetFocus
    End If
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: General [suggestions](http://blogs.office.com/2009/03/12/excel-vba-performance-coding-best-practices/) to [speed](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/SpeedingUpVBACode.htm) up [code](https://www.soa.org/News-and-Publications/Newsletters/Compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx) from a quick [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+speed+up)

Comment: Specifically for your code, it is not obvious why this is slow.  You appear to be doing a single operation (`Find`) with at most 2 updates.  Your call to `.SetFocus` may not play nicely with the event on `TextBox1_Enter`.  Although your `If` will catch this after the first go around so that should not be too bad.  Any reason you are using `.Cells(.Cells.Count)` in the `After:=`? Seems like this is the same as starting in `B1` since that goes to the end of the column.

Comment: in fact, I joined a list of products to be inventoried, and if the product exists in table 'CADMAT' he inserts the product in this list, if there it tells the msgbox that the product does not exist, however this return 'does not exist' it is taking too long and comes to seem that the table 'not Responding'. Can I help me anyone ? How do I improve the search if the item not be found?

Answer (score 0):

***Option Explicit***

Private Sub TextBox1_Enter()

***Application.ScreenUpdating = False***

Code here ...

***Application.ScreenUpdating = True***

End Sub